# Spring Data doing Insert and Deleting row immediately after>

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot/Data Api with an endpoint for deleting a record. When I send the request the Hibernate logs are as follows: `2018-04-29 18:05:04.920 DEBUG 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select max(id) from registration
2018-04-29 18:05:04.950 DEBUG 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into registration (e_id, first_name, last_name, tech, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-04-29 18:05:04.953 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [tbc328]
2018-04-29 18:05:04.953 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Fon]
2018-04-29 18:05:04.953 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Bom]
2018-04-29 18:05:04.953 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Java]
2018-04-29 18:05:04.953 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [29]
2018-04-29 18:05:04.960 DEBUG 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from registration where id=?
2018-04-29 18:05:04.960 TRACE 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [29]`

It does an `insert` and then a `delete` right after of the same record? The record I want to delete is still there yet getting 200 http codes?

Repo Here (starting an controller): https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/dac8fe092ddb8131b5069b8bc5467bfa80048d9e/complete/src/main/java/com/TechODex/controller/RegistrationController.java#L25-L30

Post man details.

URL:`localhost:8080/delete`

Request Body: `{
  "firstName": "Fon",
  "lastName": "Bom",
  "eId": "tbc328",
  "tech": "Java"
}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a new record and passing it to delete. Hibernate checks if object already persisted or not. If not, first it will try to persist object and then it will remove it.
As in your case, Object identifier `id` is null.

for more details you can check here [hibernate delete event](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Event/Default/DefaultDeleteEventListener.cs)

Comment: Oh, so I need pass in by the Id instead? Not send it a new object.

Comment: The object I'm trying to delete already exists in the DB, I read in the record and search by those values.

Comment: yes. Instead of searching first, you can use JPA 'deleteBy' query like 'deleteByLastNameAndFirstName' etc.